R package cannot find PYOMO. How do I point to the correct location of where it's located?
As a quick note this is a re-post from the main StackOverflow.
I am trying to use the PYOMO linear programming solver from within an R script. When I type
which pyomo

The result is
/home/.../miniconda3/bin/pyomo

The package in R which I am trying to use is energyRt, still in beta I guess but I imagine most other applications using an LP solver will have something similar. This is how I set the path for the solver in my R script:
set_python_path("/home/.../miniconda3/bin/pyomo
")


In other words, just as where my PYOMO solver is supposed to be.
My error message is:
sh: 1: /home/.../miniconda3/bin/pyomo//python: not found
Error in .call_solver(arg, scen) : Solution error code 2

Am I missing something? Is there supposed to be another .exe file or similar which the solver is looking for? My assumption was that the solver path should point to the same location as which pyomo.
I am running R 4.3.2 on an Ubuntu Linux 20.04.
